# Calling sh with script on stdin and passing command line arguments

Tags: bash, scripting, pipe, openssl, arguments

This works of course. I can run `./test1.sh cats` and the argument `cats` is passed correctly to `ls`.

```
$ cat test1.sh
#!/bin/sh
ls -l $1
```

Can you tell me how do I make this second example — the same content as the first one, but encrypted — work the same way?   The password is "password".  `openssl` outputs the above script, and `ls -l` runs, but how do I pass the command line argument to it?

```
$ cat test2.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "U2FsdGVkX1/m01Eg0CvZ7DiBi5Nf81+JrCWfKIDI9WtbkTZIVLhZskkKIioVfbSe"|openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc|sh $1
```

To clarify, `test2.sh` is equivalent to

```
$ cat test3.sh
#!/bin/sh
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/sh' 'ls -l $1' | sh $1
```

Comment: What do you want the script to *do* with the argument?

Comment: Same as in test1.sh, pass it to ls -l.

Comment: There's no `ls -l` in `test2.sh`

Comment: @muru There is, inside the encrypted script in `test2.sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will ask for a password, decrypt the encrypted script and run it with the first command line option passed to the main script:

```
#!/bin/bash

bash <(
    openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc <<<'U2FsdGVkX1/m01Eg0CvZ7DiBi5Nf81+JrCWfKIDI9WtbkTZIVLhZskkKIioVfbSe'
) "$1"
```

This does not use the `#!`-line of the decrypted script but assumes it will run okay under `bash` (and that it is always decrypted successfully).  The decrypt script is passed to a `bash` interpreter by means of a process substitution on the `openssl` invocation, along with the first command line argument.

To write the decrypted script to disk, run it only if it was decrypted properly (using its intended interpreter), and then delete it:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpscript=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm -f "$tmpscript"' EXIT

if ! openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc <<<'U2FsdGVkX1/m01Eg0CvZ7DiBi5Nf81+JrCWfKIDI9WtbkTZIVLhZskkKIioVfbSe' >$tmpscript
then
    exit 1
fi

chmod +x "$tmpscript"
"$tmpscript" "$1"
```

Would you want to pass all the command line parameters of the main script to the decrypted script, you should change `"$1"` in the above examples to `"$@"`. The double quotes are important as they ensure that the individual arguments are passed without getting split on whitespaces and without undergoing filename globbing.

Comment: Thanks, the 1st works also with my mysql script where command line arguments are in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You had it in an earlier version of the question — pass a `-s` option to `sh`:

```
echo "U2FsdGVkX1/m01Eg0CvZ7DiBi5Nf81+JrCWfKIDI9WtbkTZIVLhZskkKIioVfbSe" | openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc | sh -s "$1"
```

This tells the shell to read commands from the standard input,
while accepting arguments on its command line (after the `-s`)
as positional parameters for the script code coming from the standard input. 
Of course shell variables should always be quoted,
unless you have a good reason not to,
and it's probably more useful in the long run
to pass `"@"` (all the arguments) to the shell.

So it would also be wise to quote all references
to shell variables in `test1.sh`; e.g.,

```
ls -l "$1"
```

The first solution (presented above) seems to work well
for "normal" arguments. 
But, to handle the case of arguments that begin with **`-`**,
it's better to do `sh -s -- "$1"` (or `"$@"`). 
E.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
code="U2FsdGVkX1/m01Eg0CvZ7DiBi5Nf81+JrCWfKIDI9WtbkTZIVLhZskkKIioVfbSe"
echo "$code" | openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc | sh -s -- "$@"
```

(where I put the encrypted script into a variable
just to make the command line shorter,
so it would fit into the Super User display column).

Comment: Using `bash -s` or `sh -s` may confuse things in the script that uses `read`. Also, it would ignore the interpreter of the embedded script (which would matter if it was later switched out for something written in another language).

Comment: @Kusalananda: (1) Interesting.  Does your answer do better? (2) Your answer does the same.

Comment: The first part of my answer ignores the hashbang, but the second one doesn't. I never pass the decrypted script as data on stdin, so standard input will behave as expected.

Comment: Works. Thank you. I realised that I need to provide wildcard using \\* even to my original script. Example test1.sh cat* would show only one file, while test1.sh cat\\* shows all cat* files.

Comment: Yes, I had -s in my original question. Somehow I edited it many times, it didn't work anyway. It is indeed difficult to figure out that missing part -- "$@" at the end, still is.